# Making MDTextField from KivyMD works correct

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hello everyone who have faced the KivyMD lib!

The problem is that I can't make MDTextField works as I need to.
Thats the task that it shall perform:

1. User inputting the key in the MDTextField and after that press the
   button
2. If the key is correct - something goes after that (for example - toast("Key is CORRECT!"))
3. If the key is incorrect - that shall be an ERROR (for example - toast('KEY IS INCORRECT!'))
4. If there are too much characters (for example - more than 5), it have to display something (for example - toast('Too much text!'))

There is main.py:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp, pt
from kivymd.toast.kivytoast import toast
from kivymd.textfields import MDTextField

class keyinput(MDTextField):
    pass

def toast(text):
    toast(text)

class MyScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.menu_items = [
                {
                    "viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
                    "text": "text%d" % i,
                    "callback": self.callback,
                }
                for i in range(1, 3)
            ]

        self.menu_button = None

    def change_variable(self, value):
        print("\nvalue=", value)
        self.VARIABLE = value
        print("\tself.VARIABLE=", self.VARIABLE)

    def callback(self, *args):
        toast(args[0])

class MainApp(App):
    title = "KivyMD MDDropdownMenu Demo"
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def build(self):
        return MyScreen()

    def keycheck(self):
        if keyinput.text == '12345':
            toast('KEY IS CORRECT')
        elif len(keyinput.text) > 5:
            toast('Too much text!')
        else:
            toast('KEY IS INCORRECT!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

There is main.kv:

```py
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menus.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.button.MDRaisedButton
#:import MDLabel kivymd.label.MDLabel

<OptionalLabel@MDLabel>:
    halign: 'center'
    font_size: dp(12)

<MDRB@MDRaisedButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 3 * dp(48), dp(48)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    opposite_colors: True

<keyinput>:
    size_hint_x: 0.5
    halign: 'center'
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    max_text_length: 5

<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release:
        app.root.change_variable(self.text)
        app.root.menu_button.text = self.text

<MyScreen>:
    name: 'myscrn'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_y: 'center'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            spacing: dp(10)
            MDRB:
                text: 'check the key'
                on_release:
                    app.keycheck()
            keyinput:
                hint_text: "print the key here"
```

Comment: You need to assign your `keyinput` widget an `id`. Right now it looks like in your `keycheck` function, it probably doesn't know what `keyinput` means. https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to assign your keyinput widget an id. Right now it looks like
>   in your keycheck function, it probably doesn't know what keyinput
>   means. kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets

[Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8864220/erik)